# Tkinter Window Closing Automatically after one run

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

So I am writing an interface that will do some steps Data Analysis automatically. The code involves multiple screens that will be used for different functions. The first one I wrote is the EDA (exploratory data analysis) screen. The code works but will generate the report and then just close the Tk window.

In specific, when I generate the report, the code will generate the reports and then shut down. I haven't put the code generation in there because that doesn't use Tkinter. Also left out the other screens because they aren't problematic and I didn't want to dump the whole project here.

```
import HTMLCreator as sv
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
import time
import pandas as pd
import Credentials as cred
import os
class EDAScreen(Page):
   
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields = ['First X Column Name', 'Last X Column Name', 'First Y Column name','Last Y Column Name']
        self.entries = []
        self.df=""
        self.things=[]
        self.description = "Automate EDA for a Dataset"
        self.instructions = "Upload the CSV file with all the data"

        self.descriptionLabel = Label(self, text = self.description, font=("System", 13)).place(x = 140, y = 150)
        self.instructionsLabel = Label(self, text = self.instructions, font=("System", 13)).place(x = 190, y =180)
        self.genResultButton = Button(self, text = "Upload input file", font=("Arial", 18), command = self.open).place(x = 290, y = 230)
        self.edaButton=Button(self, text = "Generate Report", font=("Arial", 18), command = self.EDA).place(x = 290, y = 330)
       
        # root.config(background='gray')
        for ndex, field in enumerate(self.fields):
            Label(self, width=20, text=field, anchor='w').grid(row=ndex, column=0, sticky='ew')
            self.entries.append(Entry(self))
            self.entries[-1].grid(row=ndex, column=1, sticky='ew')


        Button(self, text='Set these Params', command=self.fetch).grid(row=len(self.fields)+1, column=1, sticky='ew')

    def fetch(self):
        for ndex, entry in enumerate(self.entries):
            print('{}: {}'.format(self.fields[ndex], entry.get()))
            self.things.append(entry.get())
    
    def EDA(self):
        sv.createHTML(self.df,self.things[:2],self.things[2:])

    
    # Get the prediction answer by searching for file
    def open(self):
        filename =  tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=self,initialdir = "./",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("data files","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
        print(filename)
        self.df=pd.read_csv(filename)
        cols=self.df.columns.values
        print(cols)
        try:  
            os.mkdir("./Breakdowns")
        except :
            pass
        # print("Things: ",things)
       
        #iv.processImg(r,'jpg')
```

It seems to be a problem that happens when you don't have a main loop. I do however have one defined as:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Toplevel()
    root.geometry("800x500")
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

The other important definitions are

```
class Page(Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def show(self):
        self.lift()


class MainView(Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        introScreen = IntroScreen(self)
        edaScreen = EDAScreen(self)

        buttonFrame = Frame(self)
        container = Frame(self)
        buttonFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        edaScreen.place(in_ = container, x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
        introScreen.place(in_ = container, x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
        
        introScreenButton = Button(buttonFrame, text = "Go to Intro Screen", 
                                command = introScreen.lift, width = 30, height = 2)
        edaScreenButton = Button(buttonFrame, text = "Understand your data in detail", 
                                command = edaScreen.lift, width = 30, height = 2)
        
        edaScreenButton.pack(side = "left")
        introScreenButton.pack(side = "left")
        
        introScreen.show()

class IntroScreen(Page):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.backgroundImage = PhotoImage(file = "What is PD.png") 
        #^^ replace with something describing how to use the tool
        backgroundLabel = Label(self, image = self.backgroundImage)
        backgroundLabel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
```

EDIT: My createHTML is shown below. It has nothing to do with Tkinter (and works). It is in a separate file called HTMLCreator. The entire file is put there. I've added import statements so that you can run the code with no issues.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series
# from pygame import mixer # Load the required library
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import sweetviz as sv

def createHTML(df,feature_cols,target_col):
    """
    Create the HTML reports for the dataset given the names
    Params:
    df: dataframe passed,
    feature_cols: The independent variables (what you input)
    target_col: The dependent vars (what you predict)
    """
    data= df
    ##TODO Set the y_all and target_cols in a way that they get Tk input
    y_all=data.loc[:, target_col[0]:target_col[1]]
    target_col_names = data.loc[:, target_col[0]:target_col[1]].columns.values
    for col in target_col_names:
        X_all = data.loc[:, feature_cols[0]:feature_cols[1]]
        # print(y_all[col])
        X_all[col]=y_all[col]
        # print(X_all[col])
        advert_report=""
        if(len(X_all.columns.values)>50):
            advert_report = sv.analyze(X_all,pairwise_analysis="off",target_feat=col)
        else:
            print("here")
            advert_report = sv.analyze(X_all,pairwise_analysis="on",target_feat=col)

        #display the report
        
        advert_report.show_html('Breakdowns/'+col+'.html')
    
    advert_report = sv.analyze(y_all,pairwise_analysis="on")
        #display the report
        
    advert_report.show_html('Breakdowns/Preds'+'.html')
```

Comment: Could it be because you are creating a `root = Toplevel()` instead of `root = Tk()`? Because I don't see elsewhere where the problem could be, maybe it is because I don't work with OOP and tkinter much

Comment: Tried with Tk(). Still the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean by closing ?

Comment: Are you using elsewhere a whileloop?

Comment: The Tkinter window closes. Like it stops executing. No errors. No while loop

Comment: Is it possible that you destroy you window accidentally?

Comment: I have no code that destroys or quits anywhere

Comment: If generating the report is the last thing that happens, there is a good chance that at least a hint to the problem can be found there. Also, I saw a `except: pass`, which is a bad habbit, as you won't even notice if an error occurs. Always at least print or log the exception.

Comment: Please read this and edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited. Also @Wups

Comment: @pasha where do you know that your programm just runs once ?

Comment: @Atlas435 Write after the EDA. It just stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have discovered the reason after using other EDA tools like Pandas Profiling. Apparently all the ones based on Pandas Profiling just down TKinter (for some reason) after finishing. There's nothing that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I did experience some problems right after an initial, partial generation of the report, but the `Tk` window, in my case, did not shutdown.

The error had to do with the following lines in your `HTMLCreator` file:

```
if(len(X_all.columns.values)>50):
    advert_report = sv.analyze(X_all,pairwise_analysis="off",target_feat=col)
else:
    print("here")
    advert_report = sv.analyze(X_all,pairwise_analysis="on",target_feat=col)
```

`Sweetviz` Only supports BOOLEAN and NUMERICAL features as targets for now, as per the documentation:

> target_feat: A string representing the name of the feature to be
> marked as "target". Only BOOLEAN and NUMERICAL features can be targets
> for now.

So that by running the code as below, the error does not show up:

```
if(len(X_all.columns.values)>50):
    advert_report = sv.analyze(X_all,pairwise_analysis="off")
else:
    print("here")
    advert_report = sv.analyze(X_all,pairwise_analysis="on")
```

Yet, passing only a numerical column as a `target` still strangely threw an error, but you can use the `FeatureConfig` object as a work around to force the target of numerical columns, if the column is not of the numerical type, you still get an error.

```
feature_config = sv.FeatureConfig(force_num=col)
if(len(X_all.columns.values)>50):
    advert_report = sv.analyze(X_all, pairwise_analysis="off", feat_cfg=feature_config, target_feat=col)
else:
    print("here")
    advert_report = sv.analyze(X_all, pairwise_analysis="on", feat_cfg=feature_config, target_feat=col)
```

Comment: There is no error in the execution for me. Tkinter just closes for me

Comment: You will have to formulate your question in a way that others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't understand. Is there something unclear about the question? The code is as is, so I don't understand why it's unclear.

Comment: I am not sure you are giving sufficient information to reproduce the problem. I am unable, with the information you gave, to reproduce the problem. for instance what do you mean by "It seems to be a problem that happens when you don't have a main loop"? Are you importing the whole code into another main file?

Comment: This is literally it. My whole code. The reason I said about that Mainloop is because that's what it said online. Do you think you can share the code you have? I'm starting to think it could be my system.

Answer (score 0):

The mainloop() has to go after the functions that are called (data analysis in your case).
Ex.

```py
tk = Tk()
tk.title('Data Analysis')
data_analysis_func(args)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I put in the main (after MainView) isn't it after the others?

Comment: What is the point of: if __name__ == "__main__":  ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do#:~:text=In%20short%2C%20use%20this%20'%20if,when%20the%20module%20is%20imported.&text=Put%20simply%2C%20__name__,run%20as%20an%20imported%20module.